# Undefined constant php error message in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

I am new in MVC framework. I created an application in Laravel Framework & it was working fine. Now after some modification when I want to view the index page the following error is shown to me-

Message:

> Use of undefined constant php - assumed 'php'
>
> Location:
>
> C:\wamp\www\alpha.team.com\laravel\view.php(354) : eval()'d code on
>   line 32

Here is my view code of index.blade.php

```
@layout('/layouts/layout')
         <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Neucha' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
         <div id="top">
        @section('navigation')
        <!-- <li class="active"><a href="/home/view/<?php //echo Auth::user()->username; ?>"><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;My Profile</a></li> -->
        <li><a href = "/dashboard"><i class="icon-book"></i>&nbsp;Dashboard</a></li>
        @parent
        @endsection
          </div>
         @section('content')
         <!-- For showing error message if any error occours-->
          <?php if(Session::get('error')): ?>
          <div class="alert alert-error">
           <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
           <strong>Warning!</strong> <?php echo Session::get('error'); ?>
         </div>
         <?php endif; ?>

         <!-- For showing success message.-->
             <?php if(Session::get('success')): ?>
             <div class="alert alert-success">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                <strong>Well done!</strong> <?php echo Session::get('success'); ?>
             </div>
             <?php endif; ?>

         <div class="field-section">
          <div class="hero-unit">
            <!-- <a id="logo" href="#"><img alt="TechIndyeah" src="/uploads/logo.png" style="vertical-align: top;"></a> -->
            <h1 style="display:inline;">Team TechIndyeah</h1>
              <ul class="teams" style="text-align:center;">  
                             @foreach($departments as $dept)
                             <?php// print_r($dept); ?>
                               <li>
                                 <a href="#<?php echo implode('_',explode(' ',$dept->name));?>"><?php echo $dept->name; ?></a>
                               </li> 
                               @endforeach
                           </ul>
          </div>
         </div> <!-- field-section div ends here-->
         <!-- <div class="container"> -->
          <div class="wrapper">

         <div class="hero-unit" id="bg-pattern"> 

          <h1 class="home-tag"> Tech-ing India<span><p>The team of enthusiastic tech fanatics</p></span></h1>
            <p class="home-ptag">We are a team of enthusiastic tech fanatics and yes we are Apple fanboys too. We have sailed out together on a small boat and we do live in what Seth Godin says, “Small is the next big”. We love technology and we love you. Our team is free, creative and always brimming with ideas.</p>
              <div class="row" style="background:none;">
                <div class="span8">
                  <h1 class="home-tag" >About Us</h1>
                  <p class="home-ptag">TechIndyeah has a team which is highly process oriented and has a sharp client-centric approach. Our mission is to help you to build your footprints in business. We are a team inspired by a vision and driven by technology. We are driven by an offbeat approach when it comes to client servicing and support. We have been serving our clients for a long time and have won accolades galore. We are a team and we believe in making our time resourceful so that our clients get the most out of us. We are a band of developers, designers and marketers who can take your business online and also combat the stiff competition from similar players in your domain.  </p>
                </div>
                <div class="span3">
                  <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/logo.svg">
                  <img alt="TechIndyeah" src="/img/logo.png" style="vertical-align:top;">
                </object>
                </div>
              </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="span4">
          <!-- <a id="logo" href="#"><img alt="TechIndyeah" src="/uploads/logo.png"></a> -->
        </div>

        <!-- <div class="span6" id="caption">
          <h3>Here We Are</h3>
        </div> -->
        </div>
              <div class="row">
                     <?php $something = $errors->all(); 
                     if(!empty($something)): ?>
                    <div class = "alert alert-error">    
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>                    
                                              @foreach ($errors->all('<p>:message</p>') as $input_error)
                                              {{ $input_error }}
                                              @endforeach 
                              </div>              
                     <?php endif; ?>                
              </div>
              <!-- For showing all employee name in the front page.. Showcasing them..-->
                   <div id="hero-unit">     
                           <script type="text/javascript">



                              //The departments are randomly comming in the page when it is first loaded..
                             (function($) {
                                     // Get the list items and hide them
                                     var items = $(".teams > li").css({opacity:0});
                                     // Shuffle them
                                     shuffle(items);
                                     // Start the fade-in queue
                                     nextItemFade(items);

                                     // Animation callback to start next fade-in
                                     function nextItemFade(items) {
                                             // Fade in the first element in the collection
                                             items.eq(0).animate({opacity:1}, 400, function() {
                                                     // Recurse, but without the first element
                                                     nextItemFade(items.slice(1));
                                             });
                                     }

                                     // Shuffles an array
                                     // Based on http://jsfromhell.com/array/shuffle
                                     function shuffle(a) {
                                             var j,              // Random position
                                                 x,              // Last item
                                                 i = a.length;   // Iterator
                                             // Loop through the array
                                             while(i) {
                                                     // Select a random position
                                                     j = (Math.random() * i) | 0;
                                                     // Get the last item in the array
                                                     x = a[--i];
                                                     // Swap the last item with the item at the selected position
                                                     a[i] = a[j];
                                                     a[j] = x;
                                             }
                                             return a;
                                     }

                                     /* Minified version
                                     function shuffle(a) {
                                             for(var j, x, i = a.length; i; j = (Math.random() * i) | 0, x = a[--i], a[i] = a[j], a[j] = x);
                                             return a;
                                     } */
                             })(jQuery);

                             $(".nav1 li").each(
                             function(intIndex) {

                             var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".nav1").width());
                             var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * $(".nav1").height());

                             $(this).css("left", l);
                             $(this).css("top", t);

                             $(this).on(
                                 "click",
                                     function() {
                                         alert("l=" + l + " t=" + t);
                                     }
                                 );

                             }

                             );

                             $(".nav1 li").each(
                             function(intIndex) {

                             var l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 940);
                             var t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);

                             $(this).css("left", l);
                             $(this).css("top", t);

                             $(this).on(
                                 "click",
                                     function() {
                                         alert("l=" + l + " t=" + t);
                                     }
                                 );

                             }

                             );


                           </script>
                            <style type="text/css">
                            .nav1
                            {
                              position:relative;
                            }


                               .nav1 li
                               {
                                   padding: 10px;
                                   position:absolute;
                               }
                           </style>

                        </div> <!-- #hero-unit ends here--> 
                        <!-- </div>  mucarousel div ends here  -->
                 <div class="member-list">
                    <!-- <object type="image/svg+xml" data="/img/vector-tree2.svg"> -->
                    <!-- <img alt="TechIndyeah" src="/img/vector-tree2.png" style="vertical-align:top;"> -->
                  <!-- </object> -->
                 @foreach($departments as $dept)
                 <div id="<?php echo implode('_',explode(' ',$dept->name));?>" class="demo">
                  <ul class="member">
                    <?php $users = User::where('department_id','=',$dept->id)->get();
                       // $users = User::where('department_code','=',$dept->code)->get();
                     ?>
                     @foreach($users as $user)
                     <li class="new-element" style="display:inline-block;" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-original-title="<?php echo $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name;?>">
                       <a href="/home/view/<?php echo $user->username;?>" rel="tooltip" data-placement="right" href="#" data-original-title="<?php echo $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name."</br> ".$user->designation;?>">
                         <img class="hover-img" src="http://graph.facebook.com/<?php echo $user->facebook_id;?>/picture?type=large">
                       </a>
                     </li>
                     @endforeach
                  </ul>
                  <a href="#top" class="scrollup">Back To Top</a>


                 </div>
                @endforeach
                   <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(window).scroll(function(){
                          if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                              $('.scrollup').fadeIn();
                          } else {
                              $('.scrollup').fadeOut();
                          }
                      });     
                   </script>
                 <script type="text/javascript">
                //all links which start with a # will have an animated scroll to the target.
                    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click.smoothscroll',function (e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var target = this.hash,
                            $target = $(target);
                            // console.log($target);
                        $('html, body').stop().animate({
                            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 10
                        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
                            window.location.hash = target;
                        });
                    });

                   $('.new-element').children('a').tooltip();
                   </script>
                </div>
                <h1 style="text-align:center;font-family: 'Lato light', sans-serif;text-shadow: 2px 1px #848686;">TechIndyeah Software Pvt. Ltd.</h1>
              </div>
         </div>     
         @endsection
         </div>
```

I cannot understand. Please help.

Comment: where is line n umber 32 code?

Comment: This is my index file & the view.php is laravel's own file which evaluate the codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share some of the code that is in your view.php file?

You're doing something wrong on line 32 of that file, so it would be very helpful if we can see what the code actually is :)

Comment: That file seems to be part of the framework, and it's `eval()`ing code - so I'd guess that the issue isn't in `view.php`.

Comment: Sorry.. There was an error in my layouts.php file. Fix it, Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but it seems that an `eval()` in a file named `view.php` is rendering a template. So my guess is that someplace in your template (whatever template is being rendered) you have `php` where you really mean `'php'`.

For example:

```
echo $data[php];   //you have this
echo $data['php']; //but it should be this
//or
if(php == $var){}   //you have this
if('php' == $var){} //but it should be this
```

Comment: @tim Did you really mean to only have a single `=` in those if statements? Seems to me they should probably be `==` so it compares rather than sets `$var`

Comment: @codeM0nK3Y Hey, he's getting an 'undefined constant' error, not troubleshooting an if statement always being true. That'll be the next question. :) Updated Yoda style.

Comment: Heh, not disputing the answer! What can I say, I'm a bit of a perfectionist ;)

Comment: Sorry.. There was an error in my layouts.php file. Fix it, Now it's working fine.

Comment: @SumanGhosh That's what I meant by 'someplace in your template'.